# how to bind the string variable to a href of anchor tag in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add the value of string variable `filename` to href ahead of TC like:

```
href="TC/'" @filename"'" target="_blank" style="color:White;"> Download TC

// code behind

filename = dr["filename"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='@("TC/" + filename)' target="_blank" style="color:White;"> Download TC</a>
```